# Появилась ошибка при деплое Django проекта на сервер

Tags: python, django

При запуске сервера выдает такую ошибку

```
django.core.management.base.SystemCheckError: SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
<class 'products.admin.ProductAdmin'>: (admin.E108) The value of 'list_display[2]' refers to 'quantitycategory', which is not a callable, an attribute of 'ProductAdmin', or an attribute or method on 'products.Product'.
```

Вот код в products/admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin

from products.models import ProductCategory, Product, Basket
# Register your models here.

admin.site.register(ProductCategory)
admin.site.register(Basket)

@admin.register(Product)
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'price', 'quantity' 'category')
    fields = ('name', 'image', 'description', 'short_description', ('price', 'quantity'), 'category')
    readonly_fields = ('short_description',)
    ordering = ('name',)
    search_fields = ('name',)

class BasketAdminInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Basket
    fields = ('product', 'quantity', 'created_timestamp')
    readonly_fields = ('created_timestamp', 'product')
    extra = 0
```

Локально на компьютере все запускается.

Comment: Если, всё запускается локально, лучшим решением будет всё перепроверить, а главное версии зависимостей, мало ли

Comment: Вы между quantity и category забыли запятую поставить. И локально оно тоже не должно запускаться - перепроверьте ещё раз, что локально вы запускаете тот же самый код